# Converting 2D Array Comprehension | m x n size

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, list-comprehension

I am creating a Google App Script and inside I am trying to create a table structure where the cell data is the value of the row heading + the value of the column heading.

I have the following Headings that represent the day and hour...

```
var tableHeadings = ["M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "S", "SU"]
var tableHours = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

I want the contents to be equal to "M0", "M1", "M2", ..., "TH1", ..., etc. So the number of columns is 7 and the number of rows is 10.

I was doing some research into how to do this and found Array Comprehensions, but I quickly found out that those are now NOT supported and we should not use them.

```
var table = [for (day of tableHeadings) [for (hour of tableHours) day + hour]];
```

> FYI, I don't know if I need to swap the 2 for-clauses yet. I am representing the columns as the days of the week. Also, I don't know if this works on m x n arrays as Google App Script does not allow for this syntax, but if you scroll down to [Array comprehensions with two arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) to see an example I used as inspiration.

In most of the documentation, I have been able to find how to convert a single-array Array Comprehension to use maps and filter, but I have not found anything on how to convert a double-array (m x n) Array Comprehension. Some documentation talks about double-array (m x m) Array Comprehension but does not discuss how to convert them.

**Is there a simple way to convert a double-array (m x n) Array Comprehension?** Just to be very specific, the solution NEEDS to work for (m x n) arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with nested [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls:

```js
var tableHeadings = ["M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "S", "SU"];
var tableHours = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];

var result = tableHeadings.map(function(day) {
  return tableHours.map(function(hours) {
    return day + hours;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

And using ES6 arrow functions you can have a one liner:

```js
const tableHeadings = ["M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "S", "SU"];
const tableHours = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];

const result = tableHeadings.map((day) => tableHours.map((hours) => day + hours));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: aha...so as a generalization, for every `for-clause` in an **Array Comprehension**, you need to have an associated `map` function for its conversion. Does that seem correct? I will test this out soon.